# Property Method not found

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

ASP.NET Framework 4.0 and C#

I have two dll, `data.dll` and `adapter.dll`. `Adapter.dll` reference `data.dll`.

For example, in data.dll I have customer.cs entity. I have added property call `Currency_Id` and data type is GUID not null. I have used it in `adapter.dll`. Built the whole project and release to production.

It is working fine. Then I have changed the  `Currency_Id not null to null`. Then Built only `data.dll` and release only `data.dll`. Then I got error -:

```
2014-04-03 23:40:49,707 [12] DEBUG SPO.ORBIS.Business.Purchasing.ApprovedVendorListController [(null)] – Method not found: 'Void SPO.ORBIS.Data.Purchasing.Dto.VendorBankAccountsDto.set_CurrencyId(System.Guid)'.
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void SPO.ORBIS.Data.Purchasing.Dto.VendorBankAccountsDto.set_CurrencyId(System.Guid)'.
   at SPO.ORBIS.DataAdapter.Purchasing.ApprovedVendorListRepository.GetVendorBankAccounts(Guid vendorId)
   at SPO.ORBIS.DataAdapter.Purchasing.ApprovedVendorListRepository.GetVendorDetails(Guid vendorId)
   at SPO.ORBIS.Business.Purchasing.ApprovedVendorListController.GetVendorDetails(Guid vendorId)
```

But If I release `adapter.dll` together with `data.dll`, it is working fine. But we are using msbuild software and only release data.dll since it is only change in data.dll.

Please let me know what could be the issue?

Thanks.
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling code in *Adapter.dll*, C# compiler does it based on the interface elements exposed by assemblies that *Adapter.dll* references. For the property of type `Guid`, there are setter and getter methods generated by the compiler that have very specifc signatures.  When such property of a class in *Data.dll* is referenced in *Adapter.dll*, compiler calls these methods. If you change the property type to `Guid?` (nullable) the setter and getter for this property in *Data.dll* will have different signatures. Therefore, the old methods that code in *Adapter.dll* calls will not be found.

You cannot make changes in the interface elements used by other assemblies and not redeploy these other assemblies.

Comment: Thanks for very specific explanation, Igor.